# Is there a way to trigger two consecutive events in Blazor with a single click?

Tags: c#, event-handling, blazor, blazor-webassembly

**Background**

I have created the card game called SET in Blazor WASM. In this game you click 3 cards and this can result in either a succesful SET, or a false submission. It works well and now I want to add an additional functionality to signal the outcome of the submission.

**Desired result**
*First method:* Upon clicking the 3rd card, the 3 cards should get a green (correct) or red (false) background and after x amount of time (say 1 second) a second method should fire.

*Second method:* If set was correct, replace the 3 cards with 3 new ones. If set was false, reset background color to white and reset border color to black.

**Actual current result**

What currently happens is that the result of the first method (green/red background) doesn't show, because there is only one callbackevent. So it does get executed, but it won't become visible until the second method is also executed, by which time either the cards have been replaced, or the backgroundcolor/bordercolor have been reset.

**Tried so far**

I tried to separate the two methods within the @onclick event, but there is still only one eventcallback and I could not find another way to do this so far, nor on stack overflow.

```
@onclick="() => { ProcessSelection(uniqueCardCombinations[index]); ProcessSetReplacement(); }
```

> The most notable difference is that EventCallback is a single-cast
> event handler, whereas .NET events are multi-cast. Blazor
> EventCallback is meant to be assigned a single value and can only
> call back a single method. https://blazor-university.com/components/component-events/

I also tried the "State Container" as described here by Chris Sainty, but that only re-renders it and I couldn't adjust it to my situation (not sure that's even possible tbh):
https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/

**Code**

I do intend to clean up the code once I get it working, making it more descriptive and splitting up the ProcessSetReplacement a bit more, but wanted to make it work first. 
If you need more background/code info either let me know or you can find the entire repository here: https://github.com/John-Experimental/GamesInBlazor/tree/21_AddSetValidationVisualisation

SetPage.razor:

```
<div class="cardsContainer">
    @for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCardsVisible; i++)
    {
        var index = i;
        <div class="card @lineClass" style="background-color:@uniqueCardCombinations[index].BackGroundColor; 
                border-color:@uniqueCardCombinations[index].BorderColor;" 
                @onclick="() => { ProcessSelection(uniqueCardCombinations[index]); ProcessSetReplacement(); }">
            @for (int j = 0; j < uniqueCardCombinations[i].Count; j++)
            {
                <div class="@uniqueCardCombinations[i].Shape @uniqueCardCombinations[i].Color @uniqueCardCombinations[i].Border"></div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Relevant parts of SetPage.razor.cs (code behind)

```
private void ProcessSelection(SetCardUiModel setCard)
    {
        numberOfSelected += _uiHelperService.ProcessCardSelection(setCard);

        if (numberOfSelected == 3)
        {
            var setSubmission = uniqueCardCombinations.Where(card => card.BackGroundColor == "yellow").ToList();
            var potentialSet = _mapper.Map<List<SetCardUiModel>, List<SetCard>>(setSubmission);
            var isSet = _cardHelperService.VerifySet(potentialSet);

            _uiHelperService.SignalSetSubmissionOutcome(setSubmission, isSet);
        };
    }

private void ProcessSetReplacement()
    {
        // If it wasn't a set submission, you do nothing
        if (numberOfSelected == 3)
        {
            var redBorderedCards = uniqueCardCombinations.Where(card => card.BorderColor == "red").ToList();
            var countGreenBorders = uniqueCardCombinations.Count(card => card.BorderColor == "green");

            // The while ensures that the 'ProcessSelection' function, which is also called, has run first
            while (redBorderedCards.Count == 0 && countGreenBorders == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(125);
                redBorderedCards = uniqueCardCombinations.Where(card => card.BorderColor == "red").ToList();
                countGreenBorders = uniqueCardCombinations.Count(card => card.BorderColor == "green");
            }

            // Wait 1.5 seconds so that the user can see the set outcome from 'ProcessSelection' before removing it
            Thread.Sleep(1500);

            if (countGreenBorders == 3)
            {
                // Replace the set by removing the set submission entirely from the list
                uniqueCardCombinations.RemoveAll(card => card.BackGroundColor == "yellow");
                numberOfSelected = 0;

                // Check if the field currently shows more cards than normal (can happen if there was no set previously)
                // If there are more cards, then remove 3 cards again to bring it back down to 'normal'
                numberOfCardsVisible -= numberOfCardsVisible > settings.numberOfCardsVisible ? 3 : 0;

                EnsureSetExistsOnField();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var card in redBorderedCards)
                {
                    card.BackGroundColor = "white";
                    card.BorderColor = "black";
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: For the next time, please extract your question to simpler problem. Forcing others to understand unnecessary details of your particular issue makes things more complicated (and longer) and decrease chance to get an answer!

Comment: Thank you, I will take this into account for the next one :) Appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to execute several timed actions in an event, `async` is your main tool.

Blazor will recognize async event handlers:

```
//private void ProcessSelection(SetCardUiModel setCard) 
private async Task ProcessSelection(SetCardUiModel setCard) 
{
    ... // old code    
    await Task.Delay(1000);    
    ProcessSetReplacement();  
}
```

when you have more than one Task.Delay() then add `StateHasChanged()` calls before them.

And in the markup section:

```
@onclick="() => ProcessSelection(uniqueCardCombinations[index])"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not call both methods in `onclick`.

- Call `ProcessSelection`, process result and set red/green there.
- Call `StateHasChanged()`
- Set timer to one second in `ProcessSelection`. Use Timer from `System.Timers`.
- On Elapsed of the timer call `ProcessSetReplacement`.

Comment: To add to this, any events in the component, which is what your page is, execute and then trigger `StateHasChanged` to effectively re-render the component. So you need to call `StateHasChanged`after the first step.  Also forget `Thread.Sleep` and use `await Task.Delay(n millisecs)`.  `Thread.Sleep` blocks the executing thread so nothing happens till it executes i.e. no UI updates.  You'll need to mark `ProcessSetReplacement` as async to use `await`.

Comment: Thanks, while this does work I found the solution from Henk Holterman to be slightly better. Still upvoted this answer as it was the first and it was definately useful. Managed to make it work.